# Create conditional probability tree in R with data.tree

Tags: r, tree

I am creating a 3 x 3 data.tree of conditional probabilities and would like the last branch of each node to be equal to 1 - sum of the siblings. The idea is that I will tweak each node of the tree and want to make sure the probabilities at the level do not sum up to be greater than 100%.

I have looked at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/vignettes/data.tree.html and see there is a way to do custom fields as a function but how do I take such an exmaple and allow the function to look at the nodes at the same level as itself?

```
    library(data.tree)

    Probability <- function(node) {

      result <- node$prob
      if (node$position == 3)
        result <- 1 - node$parent$children[[1]]$prob - node$parent$children[[2]]$prob
      else
        sapply(node$children, Probability)

      return(result)
    }

    df <- data.frame(pathString = c("R/1", "R/2", "R/3", "R/1/1", "R/1/2", "R/1/3", "R/2/1", "R/2/2", "R/2/3", "R/3/1", "R/3/2", "R/3/3"), 
                     prob = c(0.1, 0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 0.5, 0.35, 0, 0.35, 0.35, 0))

    tree <- as.Node(df)

    tree$prob <- Probability(tree)
```

The output I get with

```
    print(tree, "prob")

      levelName prob
    1  R           NA
    2   ¦--1     0.10
    3   ¦   ¦--1 0.20
    4   ¦   ¦--2 0.20
    5   ¦   °--3 0.00
    6   ¦--2     0.20
    7   ¦   ¦--1 0.50
    8   ¦   ¦--2 0.35
    9   ¦   °--3 0.00
    10  °--3     0.00
    11      ¦--1 0.35
    12      ¦--2 0.35
    13      °--3 0.00
```

The 3rd branch is still 0 and would have hoped it would be as I expected which is 1 - prob[node1] - prob[node2].

So

```
R/3 should be 0.7 (= 1 - 0.10 - 0.20)
R/1/3 should be 0.6 (= 1 - 0.20 - 0.20)
R/2/3 should be 0.15 (= 1 - 0.50 - 0.35)
R/3/3 should be 0.30 (= 1 - 0.35 - 0.35)
```

Am new to data.trees. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to do this using recursion and the Cumulate function

```
refresh.probs <- function(node) {

  if (node$isRoot) {

    sapply(node$children, refresh.probs)

  } else {

    if (node$position == node$parent$count) {
      node$prob <- 0
      node$prob <- 1 - Cumulate(node, "prob", sum)
    }

    if (!node$isLeaf)
      sapply(node$children, refresh.probs)
  }
}

refresh.probs(tree)
```

This seems to do the trick.